# How to frame JSON array from passing the checked checkbox values using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to build array from checked checkbox values in views. When form submitting checked checkbox values will form a array. I have a checkbox fields like this. Please anyone help me.

```
           {{Form::checkbox('additional_rooms[]', 'Prayer Room') }}  Prayer Room
            {{ Form::checkbox('additional_rooms[]', 'Study Room') }}  Study Room
            {{ Form::checkbox('additional_rooms[]', 'Store Room') }}  Store Room
            {{ Form::checkbox('additional_rooms[]', 'Servent Room') }}  Servent Room
```

Comment: You might want to include what framework/templating engine you're using?

Comment: i am using laravel dude

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [];

$('[name="additional_rooms[]"]:checked') // Select checked checkboxes
    .each(function(index, element) {     // Iterate each one
        values.push($(element).val());   // Put its value in an array
    })

console.log(JSON.stringify(values)); // JSON encode the array
```

Answer (score 0):

You cat get all checked checkbox values in a variable after submit form.
Example:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
      var values = [];

      $('[name="additional_rooms[]"]:checked') // Select checked checkboxes
         .each(function(index, element) {     // Iterate each one
          values.push($(element).val());   // Put its value in an array
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(values)); // JSON encode the array
});
```